# functools.partial: TypeError: got multiple values for keyword argument

Tags: python, dictionary, functools

I am using the partial method from the functools module to map a function over a range of values:

```
def basic_rule(p,b,vx=1,**kwargs):
    return (p / b) if vx != 0 else  0

def rule5(func,**kwargs):
    vals = map(functools.partial(func,**kwargs), range(1,kwargs['b']+1))
    return [x for i,x in enumerate(vals[:-1]) if x >= vals[i+1]] == []

rule5(basic_rule,p=100,b=10000)
```

Here is the error I get on line 5:

```
----> return map(functools.partial(func,**kwargs), range(1,kwargs['b']+1))

TypeError: basic_rule() got multiple values for keyword argument 'p'
```

It looks like functools.partial is trying to assign the range to the argument p, even though I have already assigned a value to it. I'm trying to assign the range to the value of vx. Any idea how I can make that happen?

EDIT: Added a little bit of extra context to the code. Essentially what I'd like test 5 to do is ensure that the result of the function given to it increases as vt goes up, so that `func(vt=1) < func(vt=2)... < func(vt=n).

Comment: What is the purpose of `**kwargs` in basic_rule?

Comment: Why are you using `functools.partial()` instead of a lambda?

Comment: Changing to `kwargs["p"] / kwargs["b"]  if vx != 0 else 0` and the function signature to `basic_rule(vx=1, **kwargs):` would avoid the  error but not sure what your end goal is

Comment: @PadraicCunningham, I have multiple tests for each function (similar to rule5) which pass arguments into the inner function and test the output. The functions don't all have the same keyword arguments, so I used **kwargs to allow me to pass whichever arguments are needed for a function.

Comment: But you never use the  kwargs. If the args always change you are going to have to somehow construct the args from the kwargs.

Comment: @PadraicCunningham, not for basic_rule, but having kwargs allows me to generalize rule5 to another function that takes argument 'x' for example (which basic_rule does not). Does that make sense? Maybe there's a better way for me to implement this.

Comment: @MoeChughtai, yes I think there might be, if you add what you want as output and why you may have better luck getting a good solution to your issue.

Comment: Good call @PadraicCunningham. I added some more context around both the code and my thinking. Your earlier comment about using kwargs['p'] and kwargs['b'] was helpful, though it might make the code harder to decipher (although that might be beating a dead horse at this point...).

Comment: If some  args might not be passed you could set some default `kwargs.get("p", 1) / float(kwargs.get("b", 1)) if vx != 0 else  0`,  I don't really see any way if you plan on passing keyword arguments to rule5

Answer (score 4):

[functools.partial](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.partial) generates a partial that stores the arguments receiveids in 2 properties:

- `arguments` stores positional arguments
- `keywords` stores all keyword-based arguments

So the partial can call original function exactly as was intended. In other words, when you call the resulting partial with one argument (let's say, 1) it would be the same as:

```
original_func(1, **kwargs)
```

As your `kwargs` contains the first argument - and you're passing the "1" as a positional argument - you get the error.

I'm not sure if it's gonna work in this particular case, but one solution could be use [inspect.getargspec](https://docs.python.org/2/library/inspect.html#inspect.getargspec) to extract arguments from `kwargs` that can be passed as positional arguments. In this case, the `rule5` function would be similar to:

```py
def rule5(func, **kwargs):
    # let's save 'b' argument because we'll need it in the range call
    b = kwargs['b']
    original_args = inspect.getargspec(func).args
    # extract from kwargs all arguments that can be passed as positional
    new_args = [kwargs.pop(key) for key in original_args if key in kwargs]
    # construct the partial passing as much positional arguments as possible
    fn = functools.partial(func, *new_args, **kwargs)
    # now map will pass the range result as the next positional argument
    vals = map(fn, range(1, b+1))
    return [x for i,x in enumerate(vals[:-1]) if x >= vals[i+1]] == []
```